# dockerizing a wine application

Tags: wine, docker

I have a 32-bit windows executable, `App.exe`

```
$ cd ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ (x86)/App
$ file App.exe
App.exe: PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows.
```

Since `wine` is installed, it runs just fine when directly executed from the command line.

I'm concerned that in the future it'll break due to missing or upgraded libraries and other dependencies, wine included.

I want to `dockerize` it, so I have a fully self-contained image that will be able to run for many years on Linux.

Is this supported by `docker.io`?

If yes, what would be the steps to achieve this (dockerfile preferred)?

Answer (score 2):

The `monokrome/docker-wine` image is based on Ubuntu and should work.

Dockerfile :

```
FROM monokrome/wine
ADD ./App.exe /
```

Note that I've tested it with 64bit executables, not 32bits.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks.  Could you please 1) Make the example standalone (not dependent on monokrome which has some python baggage and other unneeded parts) and 2) Add the step of converting the docker file to an image to make it more complete? I will gladly accept this answer after these two changes.

Comment: arielf it seems that the python baggage is not kept, instead, it is used to add a repository then removed in the monokrome Dockerfile final lines (assuming that they are the deps for software-properties/apt-add-repository). If you open that Dockerfile at https://github.com/monokrome/docker-wine/blob/master/Dockerfile, you can see the steps to install a specific wine version on a base ubuntu image.